# Excel VBA Custom Number Format Pad With Zeros

Tags: excel, vba, format

Looking for the VBA to produce this result in a column of a sheet:

1.000000

1.000001

1.000002

…

…

1.001000

1.001001

1.001002

It can be text or number.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to record macro while writting this and then debugging the code to see what has been done? There is your clue to start the code for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this is a good starting point:

```
Sub foo()
    Dim lngCount As Long

    With Sheet1
        For lngCount = 1 To 1002
            .Range("A" & lngCount).NumberFormat = "0.000000"
            .Range("A" & lngCount).Value = 1 + ((lngCount - 1) / 1000000)
        Next lngCount
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, all, but Justyna MK's solution fit my existing code best. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This would be especially suitable for a function

```
Public Function replacechar(str As String, charnumber As Integer, replacewith As String) As String

Dim startstr As String, endstr As String

startstr = Left(str, charnumber-1)
endstr = Right(str, Len(str) - Len(startstr))

replacechar = startstr & replacewith & endstr

End Function
```

You can call this function in a regular Sub, for example

```
Sub repl()
Dim newstr As String, c As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    For Each c In .Range("A1:A100")
        If not c.Value = "" Or Len(c.Value) < 5 Then
            newstr = replacechar(c.Value, 5, "1") 'replaces the 5th char with "1"
            c.Value = newstr
        End If
    Next c
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This can done using `NumberFormat` and a `Formula`. the `.Value2 = .Value2` converts the formula to an actual value

```
' Update ActiveSheet with your destination sheet reference
' Update .Cells(1,1) with reference to your starting cell - This is A1
' Update Resize(xxx) with the number of cells you want populated
With ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Resize(100)
    .NumberFormat = "0.000000"
    .Formula = "=1 + (row()" & IIf(.Cells(1).Row > 1, " - " & .Cells(1).Row, "") & ") / 1e6"
    .Value2 = .Value2
End With
```